# app crashes with ProcessStartInfo arguments

Tags: c#

I am trying to run a process called "prog.exe" with the arguments "blah $00" (sort of a code) but whatever I try fails.

```
string file = "blah $00";
string result = string.Empty;

ProcessStartInfo P = new ProcessStartInfo(@"""" + "prog.exe" + @"""");
P.Arguments = @"""" + file + @"""";
P.CreateNoWindow = true;
P.UseShellExecute = false;
P.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Process.Start(P);

using (Process process = Process.Start(P))
{
    using (StreamReader str = process.StandardOutput)
         result = str.ReadToEnd();
}

MessageBox.Show(result);
```

When this code is executed, my program just crashes and I am forced to close it using the Task Manager.

I am not sure what's wrong with my code (am I not setting the arguments correctly?), so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you double quoting everything? did you have a look at what the commandline looks like?

Comment: Have you tried it without the `@""""`s?

Comment: Why do you need quotes around prog.exe?

Comment: Is prog.exe also a program that you wrote?

Comment: Is it required that you start the process twice? You are starting `P` before your `using` statement and then again as part of the `using` declaration ...

Comment: I quoted everything because I was under the assumption you needed to use them if the arguments have spaces in them. Anyhow, even with removing the quotes I still get the same problem.
Brian: No, it isn't. It's a tool made by something else that works perfectly fine when I use it directly.
IAbstract: Mistake on my part. I removed the first Process.Start(P) but it still didn't fix the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your process with given argument from console and see what happens. If result is something you expect, just remove double quotes and this should resolve your problem.

Comment: Would I have to remove the double quotes from both prog.exe and the arguments, BTW?

Comment: For prog.exe for sure, just provide correct full path, for arguments instead, if your arguments are Blah and $00, so you have 2 arguments remove quotes, if it'is one argument use "\"".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your program crashes. It just waits for "prog.exe" to finish! I bet, that your program continues running as soon as you are done working with prog.exe and close it - and make sure in task manager that it really is gone.

Comment: The problem is, the CPU usage skyrockets to 100% and my PC crashes until I close it using the Task Manager. It shouldn't take more than 5 seconds or so for prog.exe to finish.

Comment: Which of the programs causes the CPU usage? Your program or prog.exe?